# Django - Cannot remove parameter from URL after redirect

Tags: django, redirect, instagram-api

The authentication process of the instagram api returns an access token attached as a parameter to the redirect url, e.g. redirect.com/#access_token=xxx

I am currently working on getting the access token, saving it in a session and then redirecting to a different url. However after the redirect i simply get 'http://example.com/your-name/search/#access_token=xxx' and the parameter is still there. I have tried using

```
GET = request.GET.copy()
GET.pop('#access_token')
```

but I get a 'KeyError' although the the key 'access_token' is clearly there.

See below my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

From . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^search/', views.get_name, name='get_name'),
   url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and the below view.py

```
def index(request):

token = request.session.get('token')
if not token:
    token=request.GET.get('#access_token')

request.session['token'] = token

return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to='http://example.com/your-name/search/')
```

Comment: No, the Instagram API does not do that. It would be pointless for it to do so, as the fragment (the bit after the #) does not get sent to the server.

Comment: You can't read fragments on the server side.

Comment: try: `request.GET.get('access_token')` without `#`

Answer (score 1):

if you have url with "#something" at the end (called "fragment"), e.g. "http://myserver/#something" and you will click on such a link, the fragment part  will not be sent to the server, so you have no way to read it.

This behavior is described in [RFC3986 section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> Fragment identifiers have a special role in information retrieval
> systems as the primary form of client-side indirect referencing,
> allowing an author to specifically identify aspects of an existing
> resource that are only indirectly provided by the resource owner.  As
> such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

as such, fragment cant be used in server processing or redirects.